# Weekly scheduling in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar, scheduling

I want to allow teachers to be able to login to my Rails 3.2 app and be able to set when they are available. So instead of having two `datetime` fields where an actual date is stored is stored for `starts_at` and `ends_at`, I'd like for them just to say I'm available on "Mondays between 4:00pm and 5:00pm" with all three values being dropdowns.

The orignal way I approached this was having a string for day and using the `time_select` method in my form for my `starts_at` and `ends_at`. Unfortunately, `time_select` still comes with the date.

I'm just looking for the cleanest way to allow weekly scheduling. Is this possible? If it is, is there an easier way to do this? Thanks in advance for your tips.

Comment: You could change time_select to just a simple select with literal string options for the hours.  Seems like you don't care about having a date object, so you may as well ditch it.  Just my opinion, not really an answer...

Comment: Rather than strings, if you need to do any sort of date math (i.e. figuring out if a given day-time pair is within a teacher's schedule), it might make sense to store integers of the different date parts.  E.g. (0..6) for day of week, (0..12) or (0..24) for hour, and (0..60) for minute.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at 
https://github.com/mzararagoza/rails-fullcalendar-icecube
its a small appointment app that i think that you can take allot out of it.